# Creating index for keys larger than 2KB

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have a data structure resembling the following:

```
{
   "translations": [
          {
              "source": " .... ",
              "target": " .... ",
              "targetLang": " ... ",
              "translationType": " ... "
          }
   ]

}
```

Here the source string can be more than 2 KB. If I try to create an index like the following:

```
db.TM.createIndex( { "translations.source": 1, 
  "translations.target": 1, 
  "translations.targetLang": 1, 
  "translations.translationType": 1 } )
```

Mongo throws an error saying `WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing  1198`

How could I create an index on `source` which can be more than 2 KB?

Comment: Index size limit cannot be changed, With that said they removed this limitation for Mongo version 4.2+ so it might be time to consider an upgrade if it's a deal breaker.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert Is there no limit for mongo `4.2+` ?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I ran `mongo --version`. It says `MongoDB shell version v4.2.3` and running `mongod --version` says `db version v4.2.3`

Comment: Make sure featureCompatibilityVersion is set to 4.2 or above https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#indexes

Comment: You should probably have another field that would be indexed that would contain the source truncated to some reasonable lengths like 100 chars, *if* you actually intend to do exact matching on source. Otherwise it seems like you should perhaps be looking into a text index. Giant indexes aren't the best idea for performance.

Comment: @D.SM Alright. Does the performance take a hit if the large strings (that are not indexed) are updated?

Comment: Performance of what and which strings  are you referring to ?

Comment: @D.SM For example, if I update a string which is greater 2KB and I update a string of just few bytes. Is updating a string greater than 2KB a costly affair as compared to updating a string of only few bytes?

Comment: I would expect so, though difference could be immaterial.